# Set const state inside a async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, axios

What's up, everyone! I'm trying to set **process** constant state inside an **async function**.
Everytime the button is clicked, the method **plotCurves** is called.

```
const [process, setProcess] = useState("");

const plotCurves = (selectedMoldingTask) => {
    async function getData() {
      const process = await APIConsumer("/process-by-molding-task-process/" + 
                                 selectedMoldingTask["Process"]);
      console.log("Process inside async", process);
      setProcess(process);
    }
    getData();
    console.log("Process outside async", process);
};
```

The time I click in the button, the constant process (**the one outside the async function**) still stores its initial state "" and doesn't store the value returned from API, which was supposed to do.

[image]

But if I click in the button again, process is not "" anymore and it stores the value returned from API.

I'm pretty sure the fact that **getData** is an **async function** has something to do with it, but as I'm a new React/Javascript developer, I'm not that much aware of it!

The **APIConsumer** component:

```
export default async function APIConsumer(route) {
  const baseUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:5000";
  const { data } = await axios.get(baseUrl + route);
  return data;
}
```

I would like to know how I can properly fix it!

Comment: Try moving you `useState` hook inside the component. Hooks need to be declared inside functional components at the top.

Comment: The hook is declared inside a functional component, I just didn't show the entire functional component here :P

Comment: Can you please provide the full code of the component?

Comment: It is not mutating as the constant process inside the async fuction will just be in the async function scope

Comment: If I change its name, nothing different will happen

Comment: setState does not change the state immediately because it is async. Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately

Comment: To get the desired output, you can use useEffect() and watch for the process state changes. When it's changed, you can then console log the output.